# Rails match model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I've got a `Match` and a `Team` model in my Rails application.

A match has two teams `team1` and `team2`. How do I set up my `Team` model to make it have an attribute `matches` containing matches when the team is `team1` and when the team is `team2` ?

Note: I'd like to be able to use it like any Rails association like `matches.delete_all` for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two associations. I used home_team and away_team instead of team1 and team2:

```
class Match
  belongs_to :home_team, :class => 'Team', :foreign_key => 'home_team_id'
  belongs_to :away_team, :class => 'Team', :foreign_key => 'away_team_id'

class Team
  has_many :home_matches, :class_name => 'Match', :foreign_key => 'home_team_id'
  has_many :away_matches, :class_name => 'Match', :foreign_key => 'away_team_id'
```

To delete all matches for a team, you need to delete both associated matches. In team.rb:

```
def delete_all_matches
  home_matches.delete_all
  away_matches.delete_all
end
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem with this approach is that you are not going to be able to access to the team through the match, for example "match.home_team"